# Trouble with align environment

Tags: align, amsmath

**Edited**

I am having trouble using the `align`environment, which I've read is a better alternative to `eqnarray`to align equations.

Hereafter I display the PDF output of my Latex code:

[image: Output]

I would like the `max` to be aligned with the `\forall`:

[image]

The code that I've written is the following:

```
\begin{align*}
\max_{\lambda,\lambda_0} M
\\
\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}, &\; \frac{y_i f(\mathbf{x}_i)}{\|\vec{\lambda}\|} \geq M 
\\
&\; \Leftrightarrow y_i \left(\frac{\vec{\lambda}^{\:T} \mathbf{x}_i+\lambda_0}{\|\vec{\lambda}\|}\right) \geq M 
\end{align*}
```

Would someone kindly point out what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't post code as pictures, it's really annoying for those that might want to test the code. Copy the code into the question.

Comment: Do you mean *vertically* aligned?

Comment: Indeed, vertically aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solution nests an `aligned` environment inside an `align*` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\max_{\lambda,\lambda_0} M\\
&\,\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\}, 
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    &\frac{y_i f(\mathbf{x}_i)} {\|\vec{\lambda}\|} \geq M \\
    &\Leftrightarrow y_i \biggl(\frac{\vec{\lambda}^{\:T} 
        \mathbf{x}_i+\lambda_0}{\|\vec{\lambda}\|}\biggr) \geq M
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the first fraction is no longer aligned with the `\Leftrightarrow`. I would like two vertical alignments: 1) `\max` aligned with `\forall` and 2) the first fraction aligned with `\Leftrightarrow`.

Comment: Ok the edited version also works, thank you.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw - When I posted the first version of my answer, I hadn't noticed yet that you'd edited your posting in the meantime. Once I saw the new version, I updated my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is the desired output:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\! % or \max would be a bit to the right
\max_{\lambda,\lambda_0} M
\\
&\forall i \in \{1,\dots,n\},
&&\frac{y_i f(\mathbf{x}_i)}{\|\vec{\lambda}\|} \geq M
\\
&& \Leftrightarrow {} &
  y_i \left(\frac{\vec{\lambda}^{\,T}
  \mathbf{x}_i+\lambda_0}{\|\vec{\lambda}\|}\right) \geq M
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok yes, this is what I was looking for - just changing places of the third `&` and `\Leftrightarrow`. Thank you. By the way, what is the purpose of the empty brackets situated at the right of `\Leftrightarrow`?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw Spacing.